# dispatching actions won't trigger render when using combinedReducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

When I don't use combineReducers:

```
const store = createStore<StoreState,any,any,any>(pointReducer, {
    points: 1,
    languageName: 'Points',
});

function tick() {
    store.dispatch(gameTick());
    requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick();
```

everything works and my component updates. However when I do:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({pointReducer}) as any;

const store = createStore<StoreState,any,any,any>(reducers, {
    points: 1,
    languageName: 'Points',
});
```

The store *does* update (checked by console logging) however the component doesn't render the change and I have no idea why!

The reducer:

```
export function pointReducer(state: StoreState, action: EnthusiasmAction): StoreState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return { ...state, points: state.points + 1 };
        case DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return { ...state, points: Math.max(1, state.points - 1) };
        case GAME_TICK:
            return { ...state, points: state.points + 1 };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and component:

```
export interface Props {
    name: string;
    points: number;
    onIncrement: () => void;
    onDecrement: () => void;
}

class Points extends React.Component<Props, object> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { name, points, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="hello">
                <div className="greeting">
                    Hello {name + points}
                </div>
                <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
                <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Points;
```

The container:

```
export function mapStateToProps({ points, languageName }: StoreState) {
    return {
        points: points,
        name: languageName,
    }
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.EnthusiasmAction>) {
    return {
        onIncrement: () => dispatch(actions.incrementEnthusiasm()),
        onDecrement: () => dispatch(actions.decrementEnthusiasm())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Points);
```

Store state:

```
export interface StoreState {
    languageName: string;
    points: number;
    food: number;
    wood: number;
}
```

When making the suggested changes (changing the reducer and combinereducers I get a new error:

[image]

my reducer now looks like:

```
export function pointReducer(state: 1, action: EnthusiasmAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return state + 1;
        case DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return Math.max(1, state - 1);
        case GAME_TICK:
            return state + 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your reducers and components look like?

Comment: @markerikson added

Comment: Please show how you get at the state in order to pass it as props to `Points`.

Comment: And what does your `connect` usage and `mapState` function look like?  Pretty sure I see the problem, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely in how you're using `combineReducers`, vs how you're writing your `mapState` function.

I'm going to guess that your `mapState` function looks like:

```
const mapState = (state) => {
    return {
        points : state.points
    }
}
```

This works okay when you use your `pointsReducer` by itself, because your state has `state.points`.

However, when you use `combineReducers` the way you are, you're creating two problems for yourself:

- You're naming the state field `state.pointsReducer`, not `state.points`
- Your `pointsReducer` is further nesting the data as `points`

So, the actual data you want is at `state.pointsReducer.points`, when the component is expecting it at `state.points`.

To fix this, you should change how you're calling `combineReducers`, and change the `pointsReducer` definition to just track the data without nesting:

```
export function pointReducer(state: 1, action: EnthusiasmAction): StoreState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return state + 1
        case DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return Math.max(1, state - 1);
        case GAME_TICK:
            return state.points + 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// later

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    points : pointsReducer,
    languageName : languageNameReducer,
});
```

See the [Redux docs page on "Using `combineReducers`"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) for more details

Comment: Sorry for late reply had to leave the house. Thanks for your time! I made the changes but I'm getting a new error. I've edited it in the OP. Would love if you can check it out :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a TS user.  I'd suggest asking that one as a separate TS-focused question.